# How to rebuild project after a test is executed

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea and executing a JUnit test that moves a file from one folder to another.

Lets say that I move a file from *tests/resources/origin/test.txt* to *tests/resources/destination/test.txt*.

After the file was moved after the successfull test, if I try to execute the test again the file is already on the another folder on the */target/test-classes/destination/test.txt* folder, so I have to click on *build/Rebuild Project*, so I can do the test again.

Maybe there is someway to do that with an annotation or with a IntelliJ Idea configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't move test resources, that's a bad idea.

If you need to test a move, first copy your test resource somewhere else (consider using [JUnit support for creating temporary files](http://garygregory.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/junit-tip-use-rules-to-manage-temporary-files-and-folders/)). Then test your move.

Of course, if you're just moving a file then perhaps you don't need a test resource specifically to test that. You can just create a temporary file and move it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using junit you can always use an
    @After
annotation to place the file back to its original path.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it would be best to first copy the file to a temporary folder, then move from one temporary folder to a second temporary folder. This way the original file stays in place and you can re-run the test easily.